# Como aplicar atributos de uma ViewGroup do pai para filho no android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Como fazer que filhos de uma ViewGroup herdem um atributo do pai? Por exemplo, eu gostaria que de configurar `layout_marginTop="16dp"` para todos as TextView filhas

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/quanty_text_view"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/order" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prezado,

Te aconselho fortemente a utilizar os recursos styles, dimen, colors e strings.
Com eles é possivel configurar "modelos" e apenas chamar pelo nome dentro do layout.
Por exemplo:
Se vc tivesse que fazer 10 TextViews identicas vc poderia fazer apenas um modelo e utilizar em toda uma vez só:

```
<style name="nakamoto">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

Para acessar o XML de styles bastar seguir o caminho conforme foto abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois é só você atribuir o nome nas TextViews desejadas utilizando a função correta e o nome que deu a "matriz".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado! Era exatamente isso que eu precisava! 
Mas não deveria eu incluir `android:` no começo da sentença?

Comment: @Nakamoto Não vejo como isso seja o que você perguntou.

Comment: Não nesse caso, é assim mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Que eu saiba só será possível implementando esse comportamento numa classe herdade de TextView.

```
public class TextViewWithParentTopMargin extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {
    public TextViewWithParentTopMargin(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewWithParentTopMargin(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextViewWithParentTopMargin(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams parentLayoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)parent.getLayoutParams();

        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)getLayoutParams();

        int leftMargin = layoutParams.leftMargin;
        int topMargin = parentLayoutParams.topMargin;//Atribui valor do pai ao TextView
        int rightMargin = layoutParams.rightMargin;
        int bottomMargin = layoutParams.bottomMargin;
        layoutParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
    }
}
```

No método `onMeasure()` obtenha o MarginLayoutParams do pai e atribua as margens dele às margens do TextView.

No exemplo dado apenas foi atribuída a `topMargin`.

O xml ficará assim:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <sua.package.TextViewWithParentTopMargin
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Ao TextView será aplicado automaticamente(herdará) o valor de `layout_marginTop` do pai à sua *top margin*.

Comment: Acredito que eu não sou esclarecer a dúvida. De qualquer forma, obrigado pelo apoio!